# how to rewrite or generate url like twitter and facebook in java

Tags: java, url-rewriting, url-routing, web-frameworks

how to rewrite or generate url like twitter and facebook in java....

Example : https://www.facebook.com/username, https://www.twitter.com/username

is there any java framework for this?

If anyone's got any ideas on how I could do this, or examples to help me that would be great!

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a Servlet Filter.

Comment: is there any example or tutorial...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a lot of options. Almost every framework can do that. Here are a few options:

- use the [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://www.tuckey.org/)
- spring-mvc allows you to map a method to `/${username}`
- map a servlet to `/` and handle the `request.getRequestURI()` or `request.getPathInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

I would use OCPsoft PrettyFaces or OCPsoft Rewrite for this:

**With [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/):**

create WEB-INF/pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping>
   <pattern value="/#{username}" />
   <view-id value="/profile.jsp" />
</url-mapping>
```

This will automatically put the value of the URL "username" into the request parameter named "username"

**With [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/):**

Here is the same thing using Rewrite, which is a bit more explicit, but also more powerful.

```
ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
   .addRule(Join.path("/{username}").to("/profile.jsp")
                .where("username").bindsTo(Request.parameter("username")));
```

I hope this helps.

~Lincoln